# Faster way of deriving equations of this type?

Tags: calculus

I am solving differential equations with *undetermined coefficients* and sometimes I have to find the second derivative of $f(x)$, taking the first derivative is a bit tedious but do-able, but taking the second derivative is a bit frustrating and very time consuming.

Is there a fast trick of getting to the nth derivative with equations of such types?

$$f(x) = Axe^{x}\cos(x) + Bxe^{x}\sin(x)$$

or maybe

$$f(x) = (Ax^{2}+Bx+C)\cos(x) + (Dx^{2}+Ex+F)\sin(x)$$

I am not looking for a final solution for the derivatives, I am curious to know if there are better ways than just applying chain/product rule over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$-th derivative of $e^x \cos(x)$ we can apply $\mathrm{D}(e^x f(x)) =e^x (f(x) + f'(x))$ where $\mathrm{D} = \frac{d}{dx}$

$$\mathrm{D} ( \cos(x) e^x) = e^x ( \cos(x) - \sin(x)) = e^x \sqrt 2 \cos   \left( x + \frac \pi 4\right)$$
$$\mathrm{D}^2 (\cos (x) e^x) = e^x \sqrt 2^2 \cos \left( x + 2 \frac \pi  4\right)$$
and similarly,
$$\mathrm{D}^n (\cos (x) e^x) = e^x \sqrt 2^n \cos \left( x + n \frac \pi  4\right)$$

for $f(x) = x \cos (x) e^x$ apply [Leibniz differentiation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule). the $x$ vanishes after first differentiation i.e.
$$\mathrm{D}^n f(x) = x \mathrm{D}^n (\cos (x) e^x) + \binom{n}{1} \mathrm{D}x \mathrm{D}^{n-1} (\cos(x) e^{x})$$

Similar can be done for $x \sin x e^x $. Or, write
$$A \cos x + B \sin x = \sqrt{A^2 + b^2} \cos \left( x - \arctan \left( \frac B A\right)\right)$$